# How can I run a Windows Docker container on Windows without "open \\.\pipe\docker_engine_windows: The system cannot find the file specified"?

Tags: windows, docker, windows-10, docker-for-windows

I am running Docker 20.10.22 on Windows 10 Pro 64-bit.

In my Docker Desktop settings, I have using WSL 2 disabled:

[image]

I have Hyper-V enabled:

[image]

I have Docker Desktop in Windows containers mode instead of Linux containers mode.

Despite this, when I try to run [this Windows Docker container](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-windows), I this error message:

```
>docker run --rm -it mcr.microsoft.com/windows:ltsc2019
docker: Error response from daemon: open \\.\pipe\docker_engine_windows: The system cannot find the file specified.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Do I need to change any Docker or Windows settings in order to be able to successfully run the Windows container?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that both "Containers" and "Hyper-V" need to be enabled.

To fix this, I ran

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName containers -All
```

in an Administrator PowerShell and then restarted my Windows computer. (Note that I already had Hyper-V enabled.) After Docker Desktop finished starting, running

```
docker run --rm -it mcr.microsoft.com/windows:ltsc2019
```

successfully pulled and ran the image.